# Finding the Antiderivative of a complex function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to find the antiderivative of $f(z) = z\log(z)$, but I am confused on how exactly to do that.

So we need to find $\int z\log(z)dz$ right? Since $z = x+iy$, then $\int (x+iy)\log(x+iy)(dx + idy)$, but then how do we split $\log(x+iy)$?

Can we just integrate normally with respect to $z$ THEN substitute with $z = x+iy$? We can use integration by parts as usual if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

$$F(z)=\frac{z^2\log{z}}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4}$$

one can easily check that by deriving $F$, one gets:

$$F'(z)=f(z)$$

and how to get $F$ ? the same as for real functions integrating by parts for example.

Comment: But why are we allowed to treat $z$ as if it were real? Why are we not forced to substitute $z = x+iy$?

Comment: Well, think of how integration by part works: It is just the inverse operation of product rule. As product rule still holds for complex differentiation, then so is integration by part. @damOhs